# Extract string in jenkins pipeline(groovy)

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a string like "AAA_revision12" and I have to extract the substring before "_" for example "AAA". I tried some regexps, but they doesn't work in jenkins.

```
String stringParser(String inputString) {
    inputString ? inputString.split(/_\d/)[0] : ''
}

$string = "AAA revision".split('-')

assert string[0]
```

Comment: you should explain better what you tried. Can you post some code example of how you tried with regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very confusing. I presume you are after a groovy snippet which will return the substring. If so:

```
String stringParser(String inputString) {
    inputString.split("_")[0]
}
```

As an example:

```
String input = "foo_bar"
desired = "foo"
assert desired == stringParser(input)
> True
```